# What CSP is safer - style-src 'none' or style-src 'unsafe-inline'

Tags: html, security, header, styled-components, content-security-policy

I am struggling to fully understand `style-src 'none'`. Based on the naming, it sounds like it would be restrictive or does it mean that there are no rules and you can do whatever you want?

Same question for `script-src 'none'` in the unlikely situation where it acts differently.

Side-note - what is the best CSP if you are using the library `styled-components` (everything is injected as inline with this library)?

EDIT:

I have read before the description of `none` from mdn.

```
'none'
Refers to the empty set; that is, no URLs match. The single quotes are required.
```

What does this mean? Does this mean that it does not block styles/scripts or the opposite?

Comment: If you haven't already been there, your first stop for [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) should probably be MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP. `style-src` applies to CSS, `script-src` applies to scripts .. and `default-src` applies to both.  "Best CSP" depends entirely on a) what you want to accomplish, balanced against b) restrictions implied by your choice of supported browser(s), 3rd party libraries, etc.

Comment: @paulsm4 I updated the question with a specific reference to mdn. My issue is that I don't find the description of 'none' clear in terms what it's affect will be.

Comment: Note the word "unsafe" in "unsafe-inline".  It wasn't intended to be subtle! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A policy source of `'none'` is the *MOST* restrictive; it means *NO* hosts are valid.

From the link I cited above:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
>
> Let's consider a page located at http://example.com/signup.html. It
> uses the following policy, disallowing everything but stylesheets from
> cdn.example.com.
>
> ```
> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src cdn.example.com; report-uri /_/csp-reports
> ```